# How to use Inversify with Mocha

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, inversifyjs

I'm using Inversify for Dependency Injection in my TypeScript Node.js application. This works great when actually running the app.

However, the `@injectable()` annotation seems to have crippled my tests. When running tests, I now get an error saying:

```
TypeError: Reflect.hasOwnMetadata is not a function
```

I've seen this before, and was helped by this other SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43115660/4003671

However, importing `inversify.config` does not solve the problem in my tests. If I remove the `@injectable()` annotation from the class I'm testing, then the tests run.

I don't actually need DI in my tests, so somehow disabling it would be an acceptable solution.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I've got it. Importing my entire `inversify.config` didn't work, but if I specifically `import "reflect-metadata"` at the top of my unit test, it's all dandy.